# Developing a web client without servlet

Tags: google-app-engine

I m new to appengine development.I have a few basic question about web client for appengine.When we make a google cloud module in Android Studio, an android client, a back end and a WEB CLIENT is auto-generated.A few files are auto-generated for web interface. My questions are:

1. why do I need WEB-INF/web.xml for web client? I also found there's a servlet api dependency added in gradle, though I didnt find and servlet file, what is it used for ?
2. I want to make a web interface/client for my andorid app, but I dont
   know servlet,jsp, can I make it with pure javascript or js lib?
3. Will the default template for web client work from any other web-hosting
   than appengine?
4. How can I make a web client with pure javascript,css,html, will the
   google cloud doc for javascript suffice for this purpose?

Comment: Please ask **one** question per StackOverflow question, not **four**.

Comment: a short answer will suffice ...thnk u

Comment: @Tanvir that doesn't mean the question is any better. Stack is suited for ONE question per post. What if someone answers 1&3, and someone answers 2&4. Which do you accept/upvote for posterity and the next users who come with a similar question?

Comment: sorry . I thought all the questions could have been answered in short, as I got such answer before. If u read carefully , ques 2 - 4 can be satisfied with simple Yes or NO

Comment: @Tanvir doesn't change my point. If I answer 1 & 2, Alex Martelli answers 3 & 4... WHICH ANSWER DO YOU ACCEPT? Stack's purpose is to have Q&As for the next users with your question. The way you ask this : 1) there is no chance anyone will look for this question. 2) There's no way to indicate multiple answers as the valid one.

Comment: @Tanvir and.... question 4 is a how question. Hard to answer with yes or no

Comment: what shud I do now, re-write my question ? there's a already a downvote in that, or I shud delete it and ask again

Answer (score 0):

> why do I need WEB-INF/web.xml for web client? I also found there's a
>   servlet api dependency added in gradle, though I didnt find and
>   servlet file, what is it used for ?

Both are base elements for Java web applications even though you are not using servlets most modern web frameworks are built on top of them.

> I want to make a web interface/client for my andorid app, but I dont
>   know servlet,jsp, can I make it with pure javascript or js lib?

Yes, GAE are standard web applications so you can build and app using pure HTML + js.

> Will the default template for web client work from any other
>   web-hosting than appengine?

short answer, no. The App engine SDK depends on several APIs available strictly on the GAE environment. Shouldn't be hard to get an empty webapp template working on a tomcat thought.

> How can I make a web client with pure javascript,css,html, will the
>   google cloud doc for javascript suffice for this purpose?

I dont know exactly what you mean by "the Google cloud Doc" but mostly the answer is yes, all App Engine, Cloud Compute and Google Drive are capable of hosting HTML+JS.